# Check Checkbox that Checks another Checkbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Code: [jsfiddle.net/bVgwc/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/bVgwc/2/)

I can NOT produce a jquery code to make Darc checked (below) when I manually check Darc (above)
And the same with the rest two.
check Darc above --> Darc needs to be automatically checked below
check LaVoiture above --> Lavoiture needs to be automatically checked below
check Gerli above --> Gerli needs to be automatically checked below.

Makes sense?

Ive made another jquery code for another exact same situation BUT I cant adapt it for this case.

Can somebody please write the code in that link i posted above where its the live code?

Guys, this code works BUT its for that particular situation:
jsfiddle.net/F7nBL/6/

Can soembody ADAPT it to this current situation taht im presenting here? maybe this way is easier

Comment: Say that 10 times, fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/bVgwc/6/) *note actually fixed now. did a fork instead of an update...

logic behid it is, give all checkboxes the same class, 'checkDbl' and give each matching pair of checkboxes the same class, Darc, VL, Geril and a rel that matches that second class. then tie a onChange to the class checkDbl that changes all elements fo the class that is the same as THIS rel to be the same checked state...

```
 $('.checkDbl').change(function(){
       $('.'+$(this).attr('rel')).attr('checked',$(this).attr('checked'));
    });
```

Comment: The checkDbl class wasn't assigned to the checkboxes when I looked.

Comment: I understand what your u are saying but its not working when u check it

Comment: you are my hero, btw how can i contact you? maybe i can hire you in the near future for other projects

Comment: find me by way of fatherstorm.com

Comment: @Father You are creating the $(this) object two times. You can optimize your code by caching the object: `var $this = $(this); `

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for code that works on your existing HTML, the following should work

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var fieldName = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf("_")+1);
    var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
    $("div label").each(function(){
        var text= $(this).text().trim();
        if (fieldName == text){
            $(this).find("input").attr("checked",checked);
        }

    });
});
```

It is probably not the most efficient code, but it does the job.
Not that you'll need to change the id of the Darc checkbox to `CustomFields[25_3]_Darc` instead of `CustomFields[25_3]_Dark` for it to work on the Darc checkbox.